# SSL Certificate not active with WWW prefix, add redirect in Plesk?

Tags: security, ssl, plesk

Purchased an SSL certificate for my VPS a few days ago, and got it set up finally, but noticed a few things...

When I enter the website at http://www.mirageot.com, it works fine but clearly the SSL isn't active because I'm still using http, not https. Same applies for http://mirageot.com. I don't mind this, I'd like to forward these requests to https://mirageot.com, if possible, but I can live with it if needs be.

The bigger issue is that I set the SSL up and if I visit https://www.mirageot.com/ then the SSL doesn't appear to work, whereas if I visit https://mirageot.com it does. I understand that the SSL certificate only works for 1 subdomain (or at least some only work for 1 subdomain), and I assume that I've simply entered the URL without that subdomain, but surely I can at least forward connections which have www. or are not https:// to the correct domain?

If anybody could explain to me (in simple terms) how to go about this, that would be wonderful. I've seen another question, which I'm potentially duplicating, but I don't understand the answers, they are not simple enough for me to understand. That question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637283/ssl-certificate-for-www-and-www-free-within-plesk-and-plesk-admin-panel).

FYI I am using Windows 2008 server with Parallels Plesk 11.0. The SSL certificate is only in 2 parts, the certificate and some key, but I don't suspect this to be the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Did you purchase SSL cert for exactly "www.mirageot.com" or for "mirageot.com"?

Comment: In other words, does Plesk generate CSR for "www.mirageot.com" domain or for "mirageot.com"?

Comment: Apologies for the slow response, I generated the certificate for mirageot.com, without the prefix...